# How to make binary search even faster?

Tags: c#, dictionary, search, binary

i've got some problem devoted binary search. Task is to find right border via binary search. This code works properly, but the problem is that it's not fast enough.How can i deal with it?

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 namespace Autocomplete
 {
public class RightBorderTask
{
    public static int GetRightBorderIndex(IReadOnlyList<string> phrases,
                                           string prefix, int left, int right)
    {
        var middle = (right + left) / 2;
        while (left < right)
        {
            middle = (right + left) / 2;
            if (string.Compare(prefix, phrases[middle],
                               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
                right = middle;
            else left = middle + 1;
        }
        return (string.Compare(prefix, phrases[left - 1],
                               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                               >= 0) ? right : -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If all you have is a sorted list, you probably cannot get faster. If you can change the data structure, a trie would be probably better.

Comment: You could create a Lookup into your list if you need to search it alot and it doesn't change often.  But that's not really speeding up binary search.

Comment: Your bottleneck is not the binary search algorithm itself, its `string.Compare` and it seems you are kind of stuck with it.

Comment: Small improvements: you can remove the line `var middle = (right + left) / 2;` and declare `middle` where it is assigned. And you could drop out of the loop if the Compare is zero. Also you could make the phrases all Upper case and also the thing you are searching for. This would allow case sensitive comparison, which will be faster, with a one-off cost for upshifting the collection.